# Common file folder design for django and react

Tags: reactjs, django

I am using django and react as frontend. so my project folder is like this

```
djangoproj/ #django project
  --djangoproj/
  --defapp/
  --static/defapp/mysample.wav
  --frontend/ #react
    --node_module/
    --public/
    --src/
```

I create the wave file by `python` code and use the file from `React` frontend

For now,

I put `mysample.wave` in `static/defapp` folder

However in this case, frontend `react` can't access `static/defapp` directory(is it correct?)

Next idea,

put the file in `frontend/public` folder.

However is it good?? because `frontend` and `django` independency is corrupted.

How is the best practice in this case??

---

I have tried @Daniel Morell suggested way to load the file.

`wavesurfer.load("http://localhost:8000/static/defapp/mysample.wav")`

However this error happens.

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/static/defapp/mysample.wav'
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I already set CORS setting in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', # 
]
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000'
]
```

and used django API in the same script with no error.   `axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/results/')`

---

it works.Just simply calling the file.

So the problem is wavesurfer.load()...

```
        <audio controls>
        <source src="http://localhost:8000/static/defapp/sample.wav"></source>
        </audio>
```

Comment: Are you serving your wave file to your react frontend via HTTP with the rest of your static files? Because, if you are, than you just need to let your react app know where you keep static assets e.g. `localhost:8080/staticfiles/defapp/mysample.wave`.

Comment: @Daniel Morell thank you. wow access from node server to python runserver , it looks good idea. However I bumped into another problem updated the article